# Is there a periodic function that $f(x) \ge x$ for any $x$?

Tags: functions

Is there a periodic function that $f(x) \ge x$ for any $x$?

It seems not because a periodic function repeats so many time so that $f(x)$ can appear at many $x$ but I don't know how to prove or disprove it.

Comment: Sketch a the graph of function on $(0,p]$, then extend that graph periodically. What does $f(x)\geq x$ mean to the graph?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: Assume such a function exists and consider the values of $f(0), f(P), f(2P),...$, and $0,P, 2P,...$, where $P$ is the function's period.

Comment: You mean they are  increasing so they will reach the value of $f(0)$?

Comment: Yes, eventually they have to pass its value because $f(nP)$ is a fixed number.

Answer (score 0):

Visual 'proof'. Consider any $x_0.$ Since $f(x)>x$ we have $f(x_0) \ge x_0$. Then $f(x_0)$ is above the line y=x. But since the function is periodic, as $x\rightarrow\infty$, $f(x)$ returns to the value $f(x_0)$ infinitely many times. Eventually, if you take $y$ large enough, $x >f(x_0)$ for all $x>y$. But that means if you take a point $x>y$ for which $f(x) = f(x_0)$, you will have $f(x) = f(x_0) < x.$ (This point must exist by the periodicity)

Answer (score 0):

Take any point $(a,f(a))$ on the graph of the periodic function. Then by assumption $f(a)>a$.

But the line $y=f(a)$ crosses the line $y=x$ at the point $(f(a),f(a))$. So if $b>f(a)$ it follows that $f(b)<b$.

In the graphic, the point on the left is $(a,f(a))$ and the point on the right is $(b,f(b))$.

[image: counter example]